# AWS Elastic Beanstalk: Launching a new Rails App

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I just started using AWS elastic beanstalk to host a web app I wanted to make. However, after following the instructions twice start to finish I get the same end result. Status shows everything is fine, but I keep getting this message:
[image]

The status is fine:
[image]

And I can view my app on localhost it just doesn't seem to work on beanstalk...
When I first ran eb init these are the settings I chose:
1) US East (Virginia)
2) 64bit Amazon Linux running Ruby 1.9.3
3) No DB instance for now.

Has anyone experienced this problem? What could possibly causing my app to not want to work on beanstalk?

Comment: What does your `production.log` say?

Comment: I, [2013-10-13T20:41:15.855258 #2382]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for 98.237.141.75 at 2013-10-13 20:41:15 +0000
F, [2013-10-13T20:41:15.858186 #2382] FATAL -- : 
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):
  actionpack (4.0.0)...
I followed the tutorial from AWS and it didn't say anything about modifying my routes so I assumed I would get the default "Congratulations
Your first AWS Elastic Beanstalk Ruby Application is now running on your own dedicated environment in the AWS Cloud" page

Comment: Can you update your post with a link to the instructions you've followed?

Answer (score 1):

After waiting a couple of hours it finally loaded my index page. I guess it just take a while for my pushed changes to show up.